# Can extjs submit updated xml as xml?

Tags: xml, extjs

What I want to do is to display an editable xml grid with extjs, update records and submit to the server the updated xml.

Is this posible?

Regards,

Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what Ext.data.XmlWriter is for.